# Push notifications using Firebase Cloud Function iOS

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Trying to send remote push notifications through firebase cloud functions. Resources I've been following achieves this through `sendToDevice` method, which takes a String as an argument. A resource from GitHub says its a "device notification token" that is retrieved when user agrees to receive notifications in app. Firebase says its a "registration token that comes from the client FCM SDKs". What should be the input here, and how to I retrieve it?

```
      // Send notification to device via firebase cloud messaging.  
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages
      // https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js
      // 

      admin.messaging().sendToDevice(request.query.tokenId, payload).then(response => {
        response.results.forEach((result, index) =>  {
            const error = result.error 
            if (error) {
                console.log("Failure sending notification.")
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [integrate FCM into your iOS app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client).  Pay attention to the part about [receiving the current registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#receive-the-current-registration-token).

> Registration tokens are delivered via the FIRMessagingDelegate method
>   messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:. This method is called
>   generally once per app start with an FCM token. When this method is
>   called, it is the ideal time to:
>
> - If the registration token is new, send it to your application server (it's recommended to implement server logic to determine whether the
>     token is new).
> - Subscribe the registration token to topics. This is required only for new subscriptions or for situations where the user has
>     re-installed the app.

So, you'll have to get a hold of this token in your app, store it somewhere that the Cloud Function can get a hold of (traditionally, Realtime Database), and query for it at the time the function runs.

Comment: I believe that the same steps are necessary for Android client following this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client  or is there any differences one should be aware of?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: could you explain in depth this section [ receiving the current registration token.] I do not understand it

Comment: Does this registration token expire? If I store it to database & read from there for notification, will it change later?