# How to send Notification in iOS when using firebase cloud functions?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been looking around many different places for how to implement notification sending using cloud functions. And the best I have found is the following: [Push notifications using Firebase Cloud Function iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197940/push-notifications-using-firebase-cloud-function-ios)

But I believe it would benefit many people as well as me, if this fragmentation were fixed with one set of instructions from start to finish.

**Thus I ask: How can I implement notification sending when a user creates something at a certain spot in firebase realtime DB?**

**From start to finish, a very clear explanation for someone doing this for the FIRST TIME.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this does the trick: https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/64

Answer (score 0):

This is in the documentation for Firebase. [This is a specific part of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_topics) that uses Node.js as an example to send a message.

Comment: Which is why there is so much documentation on how to learn how to do specifically what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: I am looking to help myself and others by simplifying the process so that people can easily and quickly integrate the tech by having the whole process laid out here

Comment: Without knowing precisely what you're trying to do, I am not sure it can get much simpler than what the Firebase team has given. I taught myself using that same documentation and found it quite useful. There isn't really a one-size-fits all for these kinds of things and they already give many examples for several types of common uses to go off of.